# Create hourly snapshots with spark structured streaming Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have a use case to create hourly snapshot of data being consumed from a Kafka topic.
I using spark structured streaming to consume data from Kafka and able to print it on the console, by following the standard documentation.
I am new to structured streaming and not sure on how to proceed with creating hourly snapshots.
Can someone please help me on this?

Edit: The current status

Suppose the structure of the event coming from kafka is

> id || name || position

where id uniquely identifies a record.
I can have multiple events for id and I want to consider the latest event.

Suppose I start the spark pipeline at 11:00 am.
I want to aggregate all events which arrive from 11:00 to 12:00 pm based on Kafka metadata and create a snapshot which can be dumped to a file.

**id || name || pos**

```
2  || ron  || 3.76
1  || can  || 2.68
4  || barn || 4.6
```

Similarly, I want to aggregate data over every hour and generate a consolidated view for the current hour and dump it to a file.

I have just written the basic consumer which prints all events to the console

```
val df = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
  .option("localhost:9092").option("subscribe", "geo-location").option("failOnDataLoss", true)
  .load.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .as(Encoders.STRING)

val query = df.writeStream
  .format("console")
  .option("truncate", "false")
```

Please let me know if more info is required.
Thank you!

Comment: How do you define an _hourly snapshot_? Please show some input and expected output data. Also, please share what you have tried and what part does not seem to work.

Comment: Not a free coding service so they say

Comment: I have added details in the question.

Comment: @raizsh Did you find my answer helpful?

Comment: I got busy with another task that I had to complete. I will get back on this and update the thread.

Comment: @conetfun Thank you for the answer. Yes, this works. But my cluster has spark 2.3 and the support for `foreachBatch` was added in spark 2.4.
I am now using arbitrary stateful processing in spark streaming and using trigger once and will schedule the job to run every hour through an external scheduler/cron.
Reference : https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/17/arbitrary-stateful-processing-in-apache-sparks-structured-streaming.html

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `Trigger.ProcessingTime` and set it to 1 hour. This will trigger your micro-batch every one hour which fetches latest data from Kafka.

Now to create a snapshot using this micro-batch, you would need to deduplicate on `id` and pick latest record based on timestamp field available in your data.

```
df.writeStream
      .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(1, TimeUnit.HOURS))
      .foreachBatch {
        (microBatch: DataFrame, batchId: Long) => {
          val snapshotDF = microBatch
            .withColumn("rnk",
              row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(desc("timestampField")))
            ).filter("rnk = 1")

          // write snapshotDF to csv with timestamp appended to file name

        }
      }.start()
```